# Parsing JSON and loading into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, stocks

JSON-https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

I am trying to take the JSON from the above link and place it in the following format(date,open,high,low,close)...

```
[
[1277424000000,38.58,38.61,37.97,38.10],
[1277683200000,38.13,38.54,37.79,38.33],
[1277769600000,37.73,37.77,36.33,36.60],
[1277856000000,36.67,36.85,35.72,35.93],
]
```

The date does ***not*** need to be Epoch time.

My code....

```
$.getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo', function(data) {
//Get the time series data
var timeseries = data['Time Series (Daily)']
var ohlcarray = [];
//Loop through each time series and convert it to JSON format
  $.each(timeseries, function(key, value) {
        var ohlcdata=[];
        ohlcdata[0]=value[0];//date
        ohlcdata[1]=value[1];//open
        ohlcdata[2]=value[2];//high
        ohlcdata[3]=value[3];//low
        ohlcdata[4]=value[4];//low
        ohlcarray.push(ohlcdata);
  });
console.log(ohlcarray[0]);//test if worked properly
});
```

The output....

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

value[x] returns undefined. Any ideas on why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: try `data = JSON.parse(data);` as you receive it in the callback

Comment: `value` is not an array, it's another object with keys like `1. open` and `2. high`. So it would be accessed like `value['1. open']`

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov, [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) automatically parses JSON,  doing `JSON.parse` on `data` would result in an error as it is already an object

Comment: @PatrickEvans you are correct, value['1. open'] works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `key` will be your date

Comment: @James Yup , thanks

Comment: I'd use `console.log` a bit more .. to print what's happening in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in the `each` loop, the `value` is not a list but an object. To access it, you'd have to grab it using keys.

```
ohlcdata[0] = key; //date
ohlcdata[1] = value['1. open']; //open
ohlcdata[2] = value['2. high']; //high
ohlcdata[3] = value['3. low']; //low
ohlcdata[4] = value['4. close']; //low
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koralarts/7c2fkf93/2/

Answer (score 0):

At this point it is already JSON. As Patrick mentioned, getJSON automatically parses json. You will need to access it with the array bracket notation since there are spaces in the property name.

```
var timeSeries = data['Time Series (Daily)'];
```

See ex: https://jsfiddle.net/dz0phhn2/6/

Comment: I see the issue with the nested properties, i'll update the example.